# Vue.js showing items

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I've a component in my `vue.js` application where I show a users `rides` that he has made within one week.

It looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="row center">
    <div class="panel ride">
      <div class="ride-title bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <strong class="ride-item-title-body">Rit van 04-04-2016</strong>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>Naam</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.user.name }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>Locatie van</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.location.from }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>Locatie naar</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.location.from }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>Uren</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.location.hour }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>Google maps</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.location.maps }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>Gemaakt op</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.created_at }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ride-item bar-underline">
        <div class="ride-item-title">
          <p>Factureerbare tijd</p>
        </div>

        <div class="ride-item-content">
          <p>{{ ride.billabletime }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>            
</template>

<script>

import swal from 'sweetalert';
import RideService from '../../services/RideService';

export default {

  data () {
    return {
      ride: null
    }
  },

  route: {
  data ({ to }) {
      return RideService.show(this.$route.params.rideId)
        .then(function(data) 
        {
          this.ride = data.data.ride;
        }.bind(this));
    }
  }
}       
</script>
```

So it's working the data is displayed. But in my console I receive these errors:

[image]

How could I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Set the ride to empty array, instead of null

```
ride: []
```

Or try to add v-if directive on `.row center`

```
<div class="row center" v-if="ride">
   <!-- other stuff-->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But unfortunately both do not remove the errors -_-

Comment: Actually you should set default value of ride to object containing nested objects: user and location `ride : {user: {}, location: {}}`